# How do I create new content type with editable fields?

Tags: theming, nodes

I want to create another content type similar to the basic page. I've designed a simple html layout with a block of copy on the left hand side and an image with a caption floated next to it on the right hand side.

I want to be able to add this as a template to the Drupal UI so that a user can pick this template and enter their copy, choose/upload an image, enter an image caption and possibly show a widget below the content based on what the page is about.

How would I go about configuring this so I can add this page template as a content type into the Drupal UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based upon the mentioned requirement, to me it seems either of the following situations:

**For Drupal 7:**

- Theming the node add page: **page--node--add--[content type].tpl.php**
- Theming the node edit page: **page--node--edit--[content type].tpl.php**

**For Drupal 6:**

- Theming the node add page: **page-node-add-[content type].tpl.php**
- Theming the node edit page: **page-node-edit-[content type].tpl.php**

More info about the same you can get from here:
https://drupal.org/node/1092122
https://drupal.org/node/1089656
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21page.tpl.php/7

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing several concepts:

1. You want to create a new content type
   To achieve that, go to

   Structure -> content types -> create new content type

Add fields to your liking.

1. You want to theme your input form - change the appearance
   Ankit gave you good pointers on how to change the structure of the input form. The rest you could do with css.

I assume you do not give access to the administrative theme to your users or editors. So you could style the input forms in the theme you are using.